# horizontal scroll cutting items off

Tags: css

```css
.width-100vw {
    width: 100vw;
}

.height-100vh {
    height: 100vh;
}

.layout {
    min-width: 1000px;
}

.flex {
    display: flex;
}

.justify-center {
    justify-content: center;
}

.absolute-scroll-x {
    overflow-x: auto;
    overflow-x: overlay;
}

.width-100 {
    width: 100% !important;
}

.height-100 {
    height: 100%;
}

.left-side {
    width: calc((7 / 16 * 100%));
    background-color: orange;
}

.right-side {
    width: calc((9 / 16 * 100%));
    background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="width-100vw height-100vh flex justify-center absolute-scroll-x">
  <div class="width-100 height-100 flex layout">
    <div class="height-100 left-side">

    </div>

    <div class="height-100 right-side">

    </div>
</div>
```

[Loom link](https://www.loom.com/share/9d75ddfe7f394ee6852f94d68df6c1e9)

When I decrease the screen width to 344px (in chrome dev tools), then as per dev tools, the layout div is of width 1000px (correct), left div is of width 437.5px (correct) and right div is of width 562.5px (correct).
But scrolling clearly shows that the left div is way smaller than the 437.5px. Why is it so?

Comment: why are you overwriting `overflow-x` in `.absolute-scroll-x`??

Comment: Because the outermost div's width is always = viewport width and the layout min-width is 1000px so overflow: auto on the main parent div tp have a scroll bar in the x-direction

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer is very simple. You can not scroll to the left past the beginning of the page. Y-axis scrolling begins at 0 and goes on to the end of the content, if you add more content it goes further, but if you move content up with lets say `top: -5000px` scrolling area will not be expanded, everything below 0 just gets cut off. Same with X-axis, everything on the left  below 0 gets cut off.

Your main div has `justify-content: center;` style which puts your `layout` div always in the center, no matter how big it is. When main div is smaller then layout div, since layout has `min-width: 1000px;` it puts it to the center and as result everything on the left gets cut off.

**Main div**
[image: main]

**Layout div (centered)**
[image: layout]

Bigger than Main div. Extends to the right and left, since it is centered, but everything to the left can not be reached with scrolling. Scrolling does not go below 0.

**Left side element**
[image: left-side]

Is actually correct size, but looks smaller because can not be accessed via scrolling.

In your case everything can be fixed by just **removing justify-center** from main div.

Comment: what if I want to have a centered scrolling div?

Comment: Depends on what you mean by centered scrolling div. If you mean you want it in center when it's smaller then container, and scrolling when it's bigger, then perhaps margin auto on left and right is what you are looking for.